# Store every substring from a string in an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, text, strstr

Im new here so excuse me if I miss anything.
I'll go straight to the point.
I want to read a .txt file and store all the words inside an array of words, so what Im doing is this:

```
int countWords(char *stringInput)
{
char const *p = stringInput;

int count;

printf("Counting Words\n");
for (count = 0; ; ++count) {
    p = strstr(p, " ");
    if (!p)
        break;

       printf("p: %s\n",p); 
       //Here I want to store every 'word' from the 'paragraph'
       strcpy(wordsArray,p);
    p++;
}
printf("There are %d words.\n",count);
  return count;
}
```

The idea is that stringInput is the paragraph. I check with a printf what is being stored in p. Can I store each word on a different array? and If I can, how can I accomplish this?
My problem here being that strstr doesn't just get the 'word' it gets the whole line from beginning until the next space(in this case...).

Sorry for such a beginner question.
Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: As long as the memory pointed to by `stringInput` is valid (i.e. allocated) then you can store as many pointers to any place in the memory as you wish.

Comment: Also, this question have nothing to do with `fread` or any other I/O function, so your title and tags are misleading.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry, its true. I just edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strstr` just finds a substring in a string. You don't actually want to find a substring; you want to find a character, which is computationally simpler. So if you just wanted to find the space, you should use `strchr` instead.

But if you want to split the string into individual pieces, you might want to use `strtok`.

All of those functions are well-described in their manpages. (`man strchr`; `man strtok`), which you should be able to read on your own machine. But they are available [online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) if you prefer to use the internet rather than a locally-available resource.